# Can I access a function internal dictionary externally in python

Tags: python

Say I have the following script:

file.py:

```
class A():
  def a(self):
    var={'a':1,'b':2...}
```

Can I access `var` externally (something like: `import file; file.A.a.var['a']`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't access it. That dictionary is only created when the method is called.

If you can modify the source code you can:

- move the construction of the dictionary to the class constructor or to the module level
- or return a reference to the dictionary from the method

Answer (score 0):

you can't access a variable because it's created when class A is initialized
so you can access it with the instance of A (with self reference, but you'll have to update 3rd line to self.var), or you can declare it static (if it should be shared by all instances of A, then you can create it as a static variable 
more on static variables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)